# What happens when only high resolution layouts are defined?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have been handed a project that is oddly constructed.  Almost all the layouts are in the res/layout-xhdpi/ and res/layout-xxhdpi/ directories.  The normal res/layout/ directory is practically empty.

So I'm curious as to what precisely happens when low-res devices run this app.  Are the layouts simply scaled down, or is something more complicated going on?

The answer may mean a lot to how much work I need todo while organizing this project.

NOTE: At the moment, testing on low-res devices is not feasible: the project only runs on a limited number of devices.  I'm just planning for the future (where we may support low-res devices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes nearest match.  So it would take the xhdpi and scale or crop, depending on use case.

Comment: Hmm, can't verify your answer, but it makes sense.  Thanks.